# Почему не высвечивается json на сайте html

Tags: javascript, html, json

перепробовала все варианты, которые нашла, но json никак не высвечивается, помогите пожалуйста

```
     <div class="country"><h2>Country</h2>
       <select id="country">
       <option value="hide">-- Country --</option>
       <option value="turkey">Turkey</option>
       <option value="china">China</option>
       <option value="france">France</option>
       <option value="italy">Italy</option>   
       </select>     
     </div>
    
      <div class="size"><h2>Size</h2>
      <div id="myDropdown">
        <input type="checkbox" class="btn" value="S">S<br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="btn" value="M"> M<br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="btn" value="L"> L<br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="btn" value="XL"> XL<br>
      </div>
      </div>
      
     <div class="price"><h2>Price</h2>
       <div class="price-input"><input class="input-text" type="text"  value="">&nbsp;-&nbsp;</div>
       <div class="price-input"><input class="input-text" type="text"  value="">&nbsp;usd&nbsp;</div>
       <button id="submitprice" type="submit">OK</button>
          <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50">
    </div>
</div>
           
<div id="goods"></div>

<script>var sex = 'male'</script>


<script>

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (e) {               
  loadGoods();
});

function loadGoods() {
    $.getJSON('goods.json', function (data) {
        var out = '';
        for (var key in data){
            if (data[key]['sex'] != sex) { continue; } 
            out+='<div class="single-goods">';
            out+='<h3>'+data[key]['name']+'</h3>';
            out+='<img src="'+data[key].image+'">';
            out+='<p>Цена: '+data[key]['cost']+'</p>';
            out+='<button class="add-to-cart" data-art="'+key+'">Купить</button>';
            out+='</div>';
        }
         document.getElementById('goods').innerHTML = out; 
         document.querySelectorAll('button.add-to-cart').forEach(function(but) {
           but.addEventListener("click",addToCart);
})
    });
} 

</script>
```

Comment: $.getJSON - функция jquery, он у вас подключен?

Comment: Что значит не высвечивается? Данные вообще приходят? Какая структура? Обложите ваш код console.log() и посмотрите, какие данные и где у вас. Так же, добавьте эту информацию в вопрос. Возможно, есть какие то ошибки в консоли разработчика?